# Auto refresh JS with appendchild command that grabs data from an external file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a chat system and I am using html/php/jquery.

How can I append a child with data from an external file to a div using javascript auto refresh feature?

The code that I have:

```
<script>
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function()
    {
        $('#messages_box').load('refresh_messages.php');
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

The code above refreshes the whole DIV with data grabbed from the mentioned document.

```
<script>
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function()
    {
        var textnode=document.createTextNode("Water");
        document.getElementById("messages_box").appendChild(textnode);
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

And the code above, appends the text to the div I want.

I want to "combine" this two and obtain the following result:

Auto-refresh an external php file every second and if there are new results (messages in my case) the messages_box DIV should be updated with the results using the appendchils JS method.

I want to create a chat messaging system that will grab messages if a new result is encountered when loading the external php fild. I want to use the appendchild method, because by doing this I will practically add a new child to the div, not refresh the whole div. I absolutely need to append stuff, not to load the whole DIV again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you are looking for is an AJAX request.

Here's how I would set this up:

1. Have a database set up to store messages
2. Have a PHP file with various functions to both retrieve and send messages to/from the database.
3. Have another PHP/HTML file with javascript that creates an AJAX request to the other PHP file on a regular basis.

There is tons of documentation on how to create ajax requests with pure javascript, but I personally prefer to used the [jQuery .ajax() function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: I know what I need to use, my question is how can I append a child to a div using the ajax auto refresh function (jquery) mentioned in my original message. I tried several combinations but javascript is not my strongest quality.